# How do I stop a sliding door from squeaking?

Tags: doors, noise-reduction

I have a sliding door which makes quite a loud squeaking sound when it is opened or closed. As best I can tell the sound is coming from the door rubbing against a metallic guide at the bottom as shown in the photo below.

[image: A photo of the metallic guide I'm talking about]

What can I do to stop the door from squeaking?

Comment: not really sure what I am looking at. Is this a pic of the side or bottom of the door? What is the white thing on the left? Is that the door? Is the brown thing the jam?

Comment: Yeah, sorry - It's the bottom of the door (which is white), and the brown is the door jam with the metallic piece at the bottom (which seems to have some white paint scraped off onto it) is the thing which seems to cause the noise.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should be able to adjust the "guides", if that's the case you could try just backing them off a tiny bit.

Try turning the screw looking bit, and see if you can slide the guides away from the door a bit.